# HTTPS SOAP web service timeout/not working

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, ws-security

I am trying to hit a SOAP web service from standalone client in java.
Generated code using WSIMPORT and it gave me interface to call the web service.

I created my main class to call web service but when I call the web service it times out.

I am writing code using IBM RAD.

The same web services gives me output when I run it using the SOAP UI tool within seconds.

I tried adding following line in my code :

```
Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");
```

But it didn't help.

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:163)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:135)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.userAuthentication(Unknown Source)
    at org.tempuri.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:26)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:198)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:205)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:409)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:975)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:105)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:104)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:333)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:291)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:85)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1020)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.EndpointAddress.openConnection(EndpointAddress.java:202)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.createHttpConnection(HttpClientTransport.java:202)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:102)
    ... 14 more
```

I'm getting the above exception.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Post the full stacktrace here, including the "Caused By". Are you consuming an SSL-secured web service or why did you add those SSL attributes to the binding stub?

Comment: Yes i am consuming SSL-Secured web service.